# Trouble with making a shell in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, process

So I'm trying to make a shell script in c. It has to do the following:
*exit on user input; quit
*process a command with up to one argument

As a beginner in internal processes and process control, I'm having trouble and could use a point in the correct direction. For some reason, it only prints couldn't execute no matter what was inputted. Here's what I have now, am I missing something? or am I doing something incorrectly?

```
    int main(){
       int total_args;
       char *arg[3];
       pid_t cpid;
       char shell_prompt[] = "console:";
       char line[MAX_LINE];
       char command[MAX_LINE];
       char argument[MAX_LINE];

       while(!0){
           printf("%s", shell_prompt);
           fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin);
           total_args = sscanf(line, "%s %s", command, command_argument);
           arg[0] =  (char *) malloc(strlen(command));
         .....

   }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity...why `while(!0)`? why not `while(1)`?

Comment: The phrase "failed to execute" is not in your code.  Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @SouravGhosh that's just how I always do it, bad habit i guess. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: It prints "Couldn't execute" because none of your `if` conditions resolved to `true`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey typo fixed, sorry about that. Taking a look at your reading, although It's hard to debug when I'm not sure my code is even correct or structured correctly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do you mean none of them resolve to true? It should just execute correctly through execvp and not print any error

Comment: See the answer posted below.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Consider using `getline` or `readline` to read each line. You need to parse each command. Study the source code of existing free software shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allocate storage for a string that you are going to copy you need to add an additional character for the `'\0'` terminator, so:

```
           arg[1] = (char *) malloc(strlen(command_argument));
```

needs to be:

```
           arg[1] = malloc(strlen(command_argument) + 1);
```

otherwise the subsequent call to `strcpy` will write beyond the bounds of the allocated storage.

Note also that I have removed the [redundant and potentially dangerous cast on the result of of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Hey thanks Paul, however that +1 is just a mistake I had from copying my code over. (Text editor wasnt allowing me to copy and paste).EDIT: NEVERMIND thanks Paul. It was the cast that did me wrong